# constantly checking a variable in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop

I checked quite a few posts but could not be sure if answers were related to what I want to do. All I could understand was to use threads.

I want to have a Server object which constantly checks a boolean value in a Client object and in case it is true server should do something and turn the flag to false.

I want this checking process to be done parallel to my main. btw server and client have to do other things too which i dont want to put in the same thread as the function that checks the client's flag

EDIT: I need to have multiple objects of Server and Client

so here is what i mean in C++ code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Client
{
    public:

    bool flag;

    void setFlag(bool flagStat)
    {
        flag = flagStat;
    }

    bool getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }
};

class Server
{
    public:

    void checkClientFlag(Client *client)
        {
            while (true)
            {
            if (client->getFlag())
                {
                    alarmServer();
                    client->setFlag(false);
                }
            }
        }

    void alarmServer()
    {
        cout << "Client Flag UP!!!" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Server *newSrv = new Server;
    Client *newCnt = new Client;

    newSrv->checkClientFlag(newCnt);

    return 0;
}
```

so help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want read any data you write in another thread, you do need synchronization: writing in one thread and reading in another without both side being synchronized results in a data race and, thus, undefined behavior. At the very least, make your flag a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I would definitely use more elaboration. Can you be more specific? How can I use threads for my example? How do i sync them? how many threads should I use? etc.

Comment: but before you do any of that you are going to have to thread things. this app will never run any client code - it will sit in the polling loop

Comment: you should google a tutorial on threads, synchronization, and c++ threading implementation (that will vary a lot depending on what c++ you are using)

Comment: I did Google it, but the examples are quite different than what I want to do. so doesn't really help. I use GNU C++ compiler, I'm using Code::Blocks.

Comment: You might want to look into `std::condition_variable` which may provide a much nicer (and less resource intensive) way of doing what you want.

Comment: Instead of continuously checking the flag on the client, the client could notify the server when the flag is `true`. You should then use a mutex for multiple simultaneous client notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition variable that will deal with this checking for you.

The idea is that you have a flag that is set to true/flase depending on whether the work has been done (set up as false and will be set to true when the work method is done).

the wait method means that the program will wait until a certain condition is filled.
you use notify to set this condition to true

Server.h

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class CServer
{
    std::condition_variable & cv;
    std::mutex & mut;
    bool & flag;
public:
    ~CServer(void);
    CServer::CServer(std::condition_variable & cv,
                     std::mutex & mut,
                     bool & flag);

    CServer::CServer(CServer &);
    int Notify();
    int DisplayNotification();

    std::condition_variable & getCondVar(){return cv;}
    std::mutex & getMutex(){return mut;}
    bool & getFlag(){return flag;}
};
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

CServer::~CServer(void)
{
}

CServer::CServer(std::condition_variable & cv_,
                 std::mutex & mut_,
                 bool & flag_):
cv(cv_),
mut(mut_),
flag(flag_)
{

}

CServer::CServer(CServer &toCopy):
cv(toCopy.getCondVar()),
mut(toCopy.getMutex()),
flag(toCopy.getFlag())
{
    flag=false;
    cout<<"Copy constructor"<<std::endl;
}

int CServer::Notify()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        flag=true;
        std::cout << "ready for notfication"<<endl;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
    return 0;
}

int CServer::DisplayNotification()
{
    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        cv.wait(lk, [this]{return this->getFlag();});
    }
    cout<<"Notification displayed"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Client.h

```
#include <chrono>
#include "Server.h"
class CClient
{
    CServer & serv;
    std::chrono::seconds sleepTime;
    bool finishedWork;
public:
    CClient(CServer & serv, 
            std::chrono::seconds sleepTime);
    ~CClient(void);
    int work();
};
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;


CClient::CClient(CServer & serv_,
                 std::chrono::seconds sleepTime_):
serv(serv_),
sleepTime(sleepTime_),
finishedWork(false)
{
}


CClient::~CClient(void)
{
}

int CClient::work()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(sleepTime);
    finishedWork=true;
    serv.Notify();
    return 0;
}
```

And the main program is

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::chrono::seconds sleepTime=std::chrono::seconds(10);

    //create client and server
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex mut;
    bool flag=false;

    CServer serv(cv,mut, flag);
    CClient cli(serv,sleepTime);

    //thread with the server
    thread thServ(&CServer::DisplayNotification,serv);

    ////thread with the client
    thread thCli (&CClient::work,cli);

    ////join threads
    thServ.join();
    thCli.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps, ask me if you have any questions

Comment: `Cserver`'s members shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: yes, but the reason is that when you start a thread the copy constructor is called so you cannot copy the mutex. that's why I put it static so that I get rid of this problem. the main point of this code is to show how to use condition variables, not the design of the server class (only a prototype). Does the rest make sense to you?

Comment: @Ahmet: does this solve your problem? Would be good to have some feedback

Comment: hey @Gabriel , sorry for late reply. I will definitely try this on my program and let you know. thank you

Comment: @do you want me to post a simpler example or detail some parts of the code. Looks complicated at first sight I admit